# "limit order" vs "at-or-better order"

Tags: trading, stock-exchanges

[Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/limitorder.asp) says that a limit order is:

> An order placed with a brokerage to buy or sell a set number of shares
>   **at a specified price or better.**

[Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/at-or-better.asp) says that an at-or-better order is:

> An order condition instructing a broker to only fill a transaction **at
>   a specific price or above** it.

Isn't "at a specified price or better" the same as "at a specified price or above"?

What is the difference between a *limit* orders and an *at-or-better* order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both mean same. Different regions use different terminology. Wikipedia describes  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(exchange)
QUOTE

> A limit order is an order to buy a security at no more than a specific price, or to sell a security at no less than a specific price (called "**or better**" for either direction).

Comment: Growing up in NYC, milk carton read "In NYC, may be sold until Midnight of date stamped. In NJ, may not be sold after date stamped." Even as a kid, I took note of these things.

Comment: Yet isn't it odd that the same place (Investopedia) use different terminology for the same things?

Comment: Investopedia is describing all terminologies just like a Dictionary. Nothing wrong. However it would have helped if they linked up the terms.

Answer (score 0):

Some exchanges make the differentiation between "Limit" ("strict limit") and "Limit or better", meaning that if the exchange is trading at 99-100 and you send a Limit order to BUY at 101, you'll get filled at 101, not 100.